# How to create interface to two class and mark methods, which I can use?

Tags: java, interface, extends, implements

```
class Rifle {
    void shoot() {
        System.out.println("rifle shoot");
    }

    void reload() {
        System.out.println("rifle reload");
    }

    void onlyRifle() {
        System.out.println("rifle!");
    }
}

class Shotgun {

    void shoot() {
        System.out.println("shotgun shoot");
    }

    void reload() {
        System.out.println("shotgun reload");
    }

    void onlyShotgun() {
        System.out.println("shotgun!");
    }
}
```

I need class Weapon, which will be use method shoot() from Rifle and method reload() from Shotgun
How can I do that using interface?
Imagine, that **I CAN'T MODIFY class Rifle and class Shotgun**

My bad realisation is

```
class Weapon {
    Rifle myRifle;
    Shotgun myShotgun;

    Weapon() {
        myRifle = new Rifle();
        myShotgun = new Shotgun();
    }

    void shoot() {
        myRifle.shoot();
    }

    void reload() {
        myShotgun.reload();
    }

    void onlyShotgun() {
        myShotgun.onlyShotgun();
    }

    void onlyRifle() {
        myRifle.onlyRifle();
    }
}

...main(){
    Weapon myWeapon = new Weapon();
    myWeapon.shoot();
    myWeapon.reload();
    myWeapon.onlyRifle();
    myWeapon.onlyShotgun();
}
```

That work that I want, but how can I do that more simply using interfaces?

Comment: If you can't change `Rifle` and Shotgun`, I don't see how an interface would help you, since you can't change those classes to implement the interface.

Comment: Whn you say you cannot modify the classes, can you still write this much in them - .. implements Weapon

Comment: is it required to create an object of weapon? or you can create any object?

Answer (score 1):

`Weapon` should be an *interface*:

```
interface Weapon
{
     void shoot();
     void reload();
}
```

Then in your *concrete* instances, you *implement* that interface:

```
class Rifle implements Weapon
{
    /*ToDo - implement shoot and reload*/

    void onlyRifle() {
        /*ToDo - specific code here*/
    }
}
```

Then, say if you have `r` which is an instance of `Rifle`, you can add `r` to a collection of `Weapon`. It's unlikely you'll ever need `onlyRifle`: `Rifle`-specific stuff will only need to be passed on construction.

Comment: This, as it stands, will recurse indefinitely. When you invoke `.onlyRifle()` on an instance of `Rifle`, it'll invoke it on the instance `myRifle` that it stores, and that will invoke it on the instance it stores, etc.

Comment: Oops. Removed the function body. The principle still holds.

Comment: Yes, the principle is right, which is why I didn't downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Try same like you used composition and using interface like:

```
interface Weapon {
 void shoot();
 void reload();
}

class ModifiedRifle implements Weapon {
     Rifle myRifle;
     Shotgun myShotgun;
     public ModifiedRifle (Rifle rifle, Shotgun shotgun) {
          this.myRifle = rifle();
          this.myShotgun = shotgun;
     }

     public void shoot() {
         myRifle.shoot();
     }

     public void reload() {
         myShotgun.reload();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have the Interface Weapon defined and have 2 new classes, lets call them MyRifle which extends Rifle and implements Weapon and MySHotgun which extends Shotgun and implements Weapon

Asking you to extend the existing class since you mention that you cannot modify the existing ones

so

```
interface Weapon
{
     void shoot();
     void reload();
}
```

And

```
class MyRifle extends Rifle implements Weapon{
// actual implementations of your methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a super class Weapon, which takes a WeaponType. Your WeaponType is an interface which has the shoot and reload methods.

```
public class Weapon {

WeaponType weaponType;

    public Weapon(WeaponType weaponType) {

        this.weaponType = weaponType;
    }

    public void shoot() {

        this.weaponType.shoot();
    }
    public void reload() {

        this.weaponType.reload();
    }
}
```

Your interface:

```
public interface WeaponType {

    public void shoot();
    public void reload();
}
```

Your shotgun class:

```
    public class Shotgun implements WeaponType {

    @Override
    public void shoot() {

        System.out.println("Shotgun shoot!");
    }

    @Override
    public void reload() {

        System.out.println("Shotgun reload!");
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Weapon myShotgun = new Weapon(new Shotgun());
myShotgun.shoot();
myShotgun.reload();
```